# LDAP query to retrieve users from a specific group

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to write a query to extract the users from an LDAP group. I tried several queries to retrieve the users from a specific group but none of them seem to have worked until now. For example, these are the queries I tried so far. By the way our organization uses Radiant Logic for the LDAP.

```
(&(uid=*)(cn=groupofUniqueNames=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=Group_Name,ou=users,o=trx))

(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=CN=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=Group_Name))

(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))

(&(objectClass=user)(uid=johndoe)(memberof=CN=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read `member` (or memberUid, memberDN) values from the LDAP entry representing the group, the most standard way would be to specify the group entry's DN as the *search base DN* parameter – not as part of the search filter. That is, the LDAP "search" operation would need these parameters:

- Base: `cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx`
- Scope: `BASE`
- Filter: `(objectClass=*)`
- Attributes: [`member`]

Alternatively you could search for the entry's relative DN (RDN), which is `cn=Group_Name`, and hope that it is unique across the directory:

- Base: `o=trx`
- Scope: `SUBTREE`
- Filter: `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=Group_Name))`

  (You should manually verify whether it's "groupOfNames" or "posixGroup" or something else.)
- Attributes: [`member`]

There is no universally supported way to match an entry's full DN using just the filter alone, although some servers implement that using operational attributes such as `entryDN`:

- Base: `o=trx`
- Scope: `SUBTREE`
- Filter – Active Directory: `(distinguishedName=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx)`
- Filter – OpenLDAP: `(entryDN=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx)`
- Attributes: [`member`]

Finally, searching for user objects using `memberOf=` queries *may* or may not work depending on the server. Some LDAP servers do automatically maintain the inverse memberOf attributes on user objects; some do not; and in some it's a virtual attribute that can only be read but not matched.

- Base: `o=trx`
- Scope: `SUBTREE`
- Filter: `(memberOf=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx)`

  Narrowing down by objectClass (standard) or objectCategory (AD-specific) is optional – use it if the group can contain other entries besides users and if you specifically want to ignore them. (Though usually a group can contain other nested groups and you want to chase them recursively, instead of ignoring them.)

  Example: `(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(memberOf=cn=Group_Name,ou=groups,o=trx))`
- Attributes: (whatever you need)